# xaxis timestamp format in python bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh, axis, figure

I have a data-frame indexes on a string with the format as 0 - 00:00:00 in which the first number is the day and the other part is the hour.
When I tried to plot a bokeh figure with the x data represented by this index, I can't see the line of the plot. How can I use the indication of the day and of the hour to the x axis?

Example of the data-frame:

```
index_plot  kW_baseline kW_opt
0 - 00:00:00    14.239.574.468.085.100  15.228.085.106.382.900
0 - 00:30:00    14.180.851.063.829.700  15.160.425.531.914.800
0 - 01:00:00    14.182.608.695.652.100  14.774.782.608.695.600
0 - 01:30:00    14.172.173.913.043.400  14.911.304.347.826.000
0 - 02:00:00    1.416.595.744.680.850   14.473.191.489.361.700
0 - 02:30:00    14.120.851.063.829.700  1.421.063.829.787.230
0 - 03:00:00    14.116.170.212.765.900  14.202.978.723.404.200
0 - 03:30:00    1.406.127.659.574.460   14.151.489.361.702.100
0 - 04:00:00    14.060.425.531.914.800  1.422.723.404.255.310
0 - 04:30:00    13.965.531.914.893.600  14.157.021.276.595.700
0 - 05:00:00    14.011.914.893.617.000  1.410.212.765.957.440
0 - 05:30:00    14.191.489.361.702.100  14.357.021.276.595.700
0 - 06:00:00    14.429.787.234.042.500  14.591.489.361.702.100
0 - 06:30:00    14.667.659.574.468.000  14.878.297.872.340.400
0 - 07:00:00    14.974.893.617.021.200  14.974.893.617.021.200
0 - 07:30:00    15.053.191.489.361.700  15.200.425.531.914.800
0 - 08:00:00    15.526.521.739.130.400  1.557.695.652.173.910
0 - 08:30:00    1.552.695.652.173.910   15.754.782.608.695.600
0 - 09:00:00    15.694.347.826.086.900  1599.0
0 - 09:30:00    15.681.739.130.434.700  16.173.478.260.869.500
0 - 10:00:00    15.829.130.434.782.600  1.676.304.347.826.080
0 - 10:30:00    15.855.652.173.913.000  16.602.608.695.652.100
0 - 11:00:00    1.590.608.695.652.170   1654.0
0 - 11:30:00    1.603.304.347.826.080   16.595.217.391.304.300
0 - 12:00:00    16.089.130.434.782.600  16.874.347.826.086.900
0 - 12:30:00    16.046.521.739.130.400  16.743.478.260.869.500
0 - 13:00:00    1.589.304.347.826.080   1.641.695.652.173.910
0 - 13:30:00    1.584.695.652.173.910   16.350.434.782.608.600
0 - 14:00:00    1.565.063.829.787.230   16.097.446.808.510.600
0 - 14:30:00    1.551.787.234.042.550   1.564.595.744.680.850
0 - 15:00:00    1.542.468.085.106.380   15.512.340.425.531.900
0 - 15:30:00    1.533.531.914.893.610   15.426.808.510.638.200
0 - 16:00:00    15.215.744.680.851.000  15.961.702.127.659.500
0 - 16:30:00    14.815.416.666.666.600  17.158.333.333.333.300
0 - 17:00:00    14.828.333.333.333.300  1.793.125
0 - 17:30:00    1483.5  19.029.166.666.666.600
0 - 18:00:00    1435.75 1905.75
0 - 18:30:00    14.380.416.666.666.600  18.813.333.333.333.300
0 - 19:00:00    14.279.166.666.666.600  1.913.875
0 - 19:30:00    14.237.083.333.333.300  18.587.916.666.666.600
0 - 20:00:00    14.221.666.666.666.600  19.565.833.333.333.300
0 - 20:30:00    14.215.833.333.333.300  1.860.125
0 - 21:00:00    14.156.666.666.666.600  18.997.916.666.666.600
0 - 21:30:00    1410.25 1.678.125
0 - 22:00:00    1.404.875   15.254.583.333.333.300
0 - 22:30:00    1406.5  1406.5
0 - 23:00:00    14.220.416.666.666.600  1.580.375
0 - 23:30:00    14.230.416.666.666.600  15.647.083.333.333.300
1 - 00:00:00    1.428.530.612.244.890   14.363.673.469.387.700
1 - 00:30:00    14.264.897.959.183.600  14.424.897.959.183.600
1 - 01:00:00    14.107.755.102.040.800  14.107.755.102.040.800
1 - 01:30:00    13.916.734.693.877.500  14.030.204.081.632.600
1 - 02:00:00    13.926.122.448.979.500  14.133.061.224.489.700
1 - 02:30:00    1.395.591.836.734.690   1.404.734.693.877.550
1 - 03:00:00    13.984.897.959.183.600  14.085.714.285.714.200
1 - 03:30:00    1.404.204.081.632.650   1.404.204.081.632.650
1 - 04:00:00    14.053.061.224.489.700  1.421.142.857.142.850
1 - 04:30:00    1.402.734.693.877.550   14.197.142.857.142.800
1 - 05:00:00    1.419.469.387.755.100   14.364.489.795.918.300
1 - 05:30:00    1.465.795.918.367.340   14.913.061.224.489.700
1 - 06:00:00    15.535.102.040.816.300  1.623.061.224.489.790
1 - 06:30:00    15.780.408.163.265.300  16.400.408.163.265.300
1 - 07:00:00    16.139.183.673.469.300  16.200.816.326.530.600
```

I would have the index_plot as x axis and kW_plot as y data.

Thank you

Comment: Are you saying "00:00:00" is representing hours? Or time? Looks like hh:mm:ss to me...

Comment: Yes, "00:00:00" represents "hh:mm:ss"

Comment: What is the type of those index values? Are they *strings*? or are they some sort of actual datetime object?